# How to change the order of horizontal li list?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I am making a few boxes by HTML list, which each box will contain a picture and text, but the whole box should a link. Anyway the list is horizontal like this:

```
li{float:left;}
```

**Video1 | Video2 | Video3 | Video4 |**

**Video5 |**

But as my list is going to be 2 rows so I want it to be like this:

**Video1 | Video3 | Video5 |**

**Video2 | Video4 |**

How can I do it?
Here is demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KjcKR/

I know it can be made by table but I was told that table is not that standard these days thats why I want to do it by lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use column-width 
http://jsfiddle.net/KjcKR/1/

```
ul {
    width:800px;
    background-color:#900;
    list-style-type: none;
    -moz-column-width:190px;
    -webkit-column-width:190px;
    column-width:190px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either change the width of your `ul` so that it automatically puts only 3 elements into the first row or split your list into two `ul` elements and give them a `display: block` and a `width` of 100% so they take the full width

Answer (score 1):

You can use use CSS3 multicolumn layout

```
ul {
    column-width: 380px;
    -webkit-column-width:380px;
    -moz-column-width: 380px;
    height:440px;
}
```

Note that this won't work in IE8 and prior though.

http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/8jw6r/

You can use this javascript polyfill for older browsers - http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/Umz6a/

Comment: So do you suggest to use table instead?

Comment: There is a javascript polyfill for this. I will post it in a moment.